# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.news">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.News"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

HERE IS MERGED MANIFEST Errors Lines

Merging Errors:
Error: tools:replace specified at line:8 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified News.app main manifest (this file), line 7
Error: Validation failed, exiting News.app main manifest (this file)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from Application tag `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`.